# No longer able to access queryPastPurchases in InAppPurchase Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-in-app-purchase

I recently updated the InAppPurchase plugin in flutter. The update is breaking the code.
I am unable get past purchases using the InAppPurchase instance.Anyone know how to retreive the past purchase?

```
Final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse purchaseResponse =await _inAppPurchase.queryPastPurchases();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use:

```
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
  await _inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
```

Comment: above _inAppPurchase.restorePurchases(); returns void. I used to get purchaseDetails before using _purchases = purchaseResponse.pastPurchases; after that i verified the purchase using my backend server. Now How do i do that.

Comment: According to the docs restorePurchases will retrieve the old purchases.

Comment: so this action will trigger the purchaseStream?.

Comment: Restored purchases will be emitted on the InAppPurchase.purchaseStream